# Unnamed process related to perfdata using 100% CPU

Tags: windows, services, cpu-usage, windows-server-2012-r2

We are currently running Windows Server 2012 R2 with an i7-4770 CPU. There is an unnamed service using literally 99.5% of the CPU 100% of the time. We can still use the server for remote desktop, but it is slightly slower than we would prefer (net not the issue here).

I've attached relevant screen shots. If I right click from the task manager window and click "go to service", it takes me to the services pane with nothing highlighted. Our mystery service has absolutely no description either (even when checking from the command line).

Is there any way to stop this service, or has anyone heard of perfdat (the file directory)?

[image: File Directory of service]

[image: Unnamed in task manager]

Comment: Hop over to the `Details` tab and see what you see there taking up the CPU? Have you went to `services.msc` and try to find any correlated service? Check `netstat`, Event Logs, disconnect from the network and see happens, restart PC with no network and see what happens, etc.

Comment: Details tab calls the service 'svchost' (as per usual), taking up 99%. As the service is completely unnamed I have no way of telling which service I should resign in services.msc. I'll check netstat tomorrow for sure. Event logs are showing nothing unusual. Unforatunely I can't restart the PC without net as we are using it in production. Thanks for your help.

Comment: From elevated command prompt run `tasklist /FI "imagename eq svchost.exe" /svc` and look over the output. Go to `services.msc` from another windows and look for correlated services you can stop one-by-one that will not cause the entire server to have to be rebooted until you find the one you stop that makes the Task Manager process stop consuming so much CPU. Once you find what's causing the spike, do some research on that. Perhaps Windows Updates are needed or a reboot is pending, etc. If all else fails, plan for a reboot 20 minute downtime or something and power cycle it.

Comment: use ProcessExplorer/ProcessHacker, show the commandline here and look which process it is

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. I was writing out a response and I seem to have figured out what the process is using ProcessExplorer. After rebooting the service and watching the logs, I discovered it was a Bitcoin Miner. Thank you again for your help

Comment: post your reply as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using ProcessExplorer to inspect the 'strings' of the mystery service, I quickly noticed that some were web addresses. Further investigation revealed it was a malicious bitcoin miner which I removed with antivirus. Thanks to magicandre1981 & Facebook

Comment: I was facing the same issue.
I used malwarebytes and its gone now.
I reccomend you to use it too.
https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/